# ImageView InflateException and app crash

Tags: android, imageview

I tried adding a single ImageView to my app. It doesn't have any other components. It still crashes.

Logcat:

```
11-23 00:04:00.841 26754-26754/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-23 00:04:01.291 26754-26754/com.example.shinchan I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
11-23 00:04:01.647 26754-26754/com.example.shinchan W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-23 00:04:01.934 26754-26754/com.example.shinchan W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060062 (t=5 e=98) (error -75)
11-23 00:04:01.934 26754-26754/com.example.shinchan W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060062 (t=5 e=98) (error -75)
11-23 00:04:01.935 26754-26754/com.example.shinchan D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-23 00:04:01.944 26754-26754/com.example.shinchan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.shinchan, PID: 26754
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shinchan/com.example.shinchan.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class ImageView
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                          at com.example.shinchan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
                                                                       Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060062
                                                                          at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:330)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:195)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                          at com.example.shinchan.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010) 
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
11-23 00:04:01.968 26754-26754/com.example.shinchan I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26754 SIG: 9
```

Java code:

```
package com.example.shinchan;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.shinchan.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shinchan" />
</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

I read other Stack Overflow answers that asked me to try using:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/shinchan"
```

instead of:

```
android:src="@drawable/shinchan"
```

and adding:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

to the gradle file.

But none of them worked for me.

I also tried 3 different pictures and the app crashed for all of them.
I used [these](https://postimg.org/gallery/2nda7x1ik/) three images.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the image to F:\Coding\Android\ShinChan\app\src\main\res\drawable instead of F:\Coding\Android\ShinChan\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24 worked.